# Passing a closure to a function expecting a std::ops::Fn

Tags: rust, closures, traits

I'm trying to use a closure to call a function on a bunch of feature vectors.  The most important code lines here are the first line, where we say what type `query` must be and the last line, where we try to give a closure.

```
fn stat_query(dataset: &Vec<Vec<i32>>, query: Fn(&Vec<i32>) -> f64) -> f64 {
    // takes in a dataset of feature vectors and a query,
    // returns the average of the query on the dataset
    if dataset.len() == 0 {
        0.
    } else {
        dataset.iter().map(|ref fv| query(&fv)).sum() / (dataset.len() as f64)
    }
}

fn main() {
    // build dataset
    let fv1: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
    let fv2: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 0, 1, 0, 1];
    let my_dataset = vec![fv1, fv2];

    // query checks whether sum of features is greater than a threshold
    fn my_query(ref fv: &Vec<i32>, threshold: i32) -> f64 {
        if fv.iter().sum() > threshold {
            1.
        } else {
            0.
        }
    }

    // run query on dataset with threshold 3
    println!("{}", stat_query(&my_dataset, |ref fv| my_query(fv, 3)));
}
```

When I run this, I get an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r std::vec::Vec<i32>) -> f64 + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:1:40
  |
1 | fn stat_query(dataset: &Vec<Vec<i32>>, query: Fn(&Vec<i32>) -> f64) -> f64 {
  |                                        ^^^^^ `for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r std::vec::Vec<i32>) -> f64 + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r std::vec::Vec<i32>) -> f64 + 'static`
  = note: all local variables must have a statically known size

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:27:44
   |
27 |     println!("{}", stat_query(&my_dataset, |ref fv| my_query(fv, 3)));
   |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait std::ops::Fn, found closure
   |
   = note: expected type `for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r std::vec::Vec<i32>) -> f64 + 'static`
              found type `[closure@src/main.rs:27:44: 27:68]`
```

I thought closures [implemented `Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html) (or `FnOnce` or `FnMut`)?  Is it not valid to provide a closure when you expect a `Fn`? I assume I need to specify something else about the `Fn` in the first line?  But what?

I assume I have incorrectly specified the type of either the `query: Fn(&Vec<i32>) -> f64` parameter of my first function, or have written the closure wrong `|ref fv| my_query(fv, 3)`.

I read [Passing closure to trait method: expected type parameter, found closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664325/passing-closure-to-trait-method-expected-type-parameter-found-closure), but that seems to be more about passing a closure that isn't the only kind of thing the function is accepting.

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String) or Vec (&Vec) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: **Please** read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch13-01-closures.html#using-closures-with-generic-parameters-and-the-fn-traits) which already addresses topics like how to pass closures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second error was the more important one:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r std::vec::Vec<i32>) -> f64 + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
```

In short: `Fn(&Vec<i32>) -> f64` is not a sized type, and cannot be passed by value.  You can only pass [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/types.html#trait-objects) (references or boxes), or values of (sized) types implementing a trait.  In this case you probably want the latter:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a09e292ba3006fbed47a961db6318242&version=stable)

```
fn stat_query<F>(dataset: &Vec<Vec<i32>>, query: F) -> f64
where
    F: Fn(&Vec<i32>) -> f64,
{
    // takes in a dataset of feature vectors and a query,
    // returns the average of the query on the dataset
    if dataset.len() == 0 {
        0.
    } else {
        dataset.iter().map(|ref fv| query(&fv)).sum::<f64>() / (dataset.len() as f64)
    }
}

fn main() {
    // build dataset
    let fv1: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
    let fv2: Vec<i32> = vec![1, 0, 1, 0, 1];
    let my_dataset = vec![fv1, fv2];

    // query checks whether sum of features is greater than a threshold
    fn my_query(ref fv: &Vec<i32>, threshold: i32) -> f64 {
        if fv.iter().sum::<i32>() > threshold {
            1.
        } else {
            0.
        }
    }

    // run query on dataset with threshold 3
    println!("{}", stat_query(&my_dataset, |ref fv| my_query(fv, 3)));
}
```